# Cannot connect to Internet, probably an ip conflict

Tags: networking, internet

My computer connected to Internet fine earlier today. Then I plugged another computer into another port of my router. This new computer is connected to the Internet and is working fine. My iPad through wifi which also is connected to the same router is working fine. But my original computer can't connect to the Internet.

Some sort of IP conflict? I know very little about computers and networking so I would really appreciate you're help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of the command 'ip addr' and 'ip route' on your computer? What happens if you unplug/turn of the second computer? What does the routers web setting page say about your local net? There should be a page which tell you which computers are connected. How does that page change when you connect the second computer? What type and os on the other computer? Edit the question with that new information.

Answer (score 0):

Unless one of your devices has a static IP, this is not an IP conflict. If it is an IP conflict, try restarting your computer. Otherwise, plug into your router and see if it helps. Then, try updating your router's firmware.